# Get/Set audience for Open Graph Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, privacy

Is it possible to get OR set the audience (FRIENDS, ONLY ME, PUBLIC) of an Open Graph Story post? According to [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post) there should be a field for the privacy setting. My application does have the publish-permission:"publish_actions" and the read-permissions: "public_profile", "email", "user_posts". 

When i make the following request (iOS):

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "postid", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
```

i get this response:

```
{
data =     {
    location =         {
        id = 00000000000;
        title = "Sample title";
        type = "my_namespace:location";
    };
};
"end_time" = "2016-02-01T09:35:35+0000";
id = postid;
"start_time" = "2016-02-01T09:35:35+0000";
type = "my_namespace:check_in";
```

}

It does not contain any type of privacy field. Is there a way to get it or even set it?

Answer (score 2):

According to

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

you can set the `privacy` field with an object of

```
{
    "value": "YOUR_VALUE"
}
```

where `YOUR_VALUE` must be one of `'EVERYONE', 'ALL_FRIENDS', 'FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS', 'CUSTOM', 'SELF'`.

Keep in mind that the `privacy` field

> Determines the privacy settings of the post. If not supplied, this **defaults to the privacy level granted to the app** in the Login Dialog. **This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the one granted**.

Comment: do you know how i set it using ios sdk and a FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent? how do i pass this field?

Comment: i am already able to post, i just dont know how to add the privacy field to an opengraph content. the facebook documentation is very poorly on specific topics.

Comment: You can't add a privacy field to an OpenGraph object IMH=. You can set the privacy on the post object itself.

Comment: Yes i do understand that. The post is published with `FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content)` where content is of type `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent`.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't support the `privacy` field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/share-button#customizing and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareLinkContent

Answer (score 0):

You must append the parameter `?fields=privacy`to retrieve the privacy settings array.

Comment: Thanks for the response: When i try adding the fields parameter to my request `FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "postid/?fields=privacy", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET") ` I get the following error response: `Tried accessing nonexisting field (privacy) on node type (OpenGraphAction)"`