# iOS Facebook Graph API get list of filters (public, friends, only me)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I need to build a custom UI to share to normal feed as well as sharing to user's Facebook Pages as a Facebook Page (the normal iOS share dialog does not give an option to share to pages, only to user's feed).

So far, I can get the user's profile info using:

```
id params = @{
                @"fields": @"id,name,picture.type(large),permissions"
             };

...
Request to @"me"
```

as well as the user's pages using:

```
id pageParams = @{
                 @"fields": @"id,name,picture.type(large)"
             };
...
Request to @"me/accounts"
```

Is it possible to get the list of possible share-to filters: `public, friends, only me, etc`? or are these values hardcoded?

Should look something like this:

[image: example design]

I'm talking about the list at the bottom of the screen which I've currently hard coded into the UI.

I want to know how to retrieve that list so user can set their privacy settings before making the post.

### Update

I found a duplicate Stackoverflow question: [Get/Set audience for Open Graph Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333989/get-set-audience-for-open-graph-post)

Comment: The answer there links to the documentation, and in there the possible values are explained. What more do you need?

Comment: The possible values listed by the documentation are `'EVERYONE', 'ALL_FRIENDS', 'FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS', 'CUSTOM', 'SELF'` but when I ran the Facebook share dialog in the past, I see more than these e.g. I saw options such as my company name and teams that I was added by other Facebook users. Perhaps these are `CUSTOM`. I was hoping for a graph api way of fetching the list of possible options but looks like I'll need to hard code the available options here.

Comment: You can read the names and ids of the friend lists the user has (needs additional permission) - those ids can be used for custom privacy as well. But that’s it.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess for my purpose it's probably better to limit the option to these 3. Makes my life easier. Thanks for marking duplicate anyhow :)